# Linux API, Write() fails even with proper File descriptor and permissions

Tags: android, c, linux

I am debugging an issue where write call is failing.

```
#define PATH_1 "/sys/p/lock"
#define PATH_2 "/sys/p/unlock"

void api_init()
{
    fd_name_1 = open(PATH_1, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND);
    fd_name_2 = open(PATH_2, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND);
}

void api_acquire()
{
    return_1 = write(fd_name_1, WAKELOCK_NAME, strlen(WAKELOCK_NAME));
    if(return_1 != (int)strlen(WAKELOCK_NAME))
         printf("error writing to file");
}

int api_release()
{
    return_2 = write(fd_name_2, WAKELOCK_NAME, strlen(WAKELOCK_NAME));
    if(return_2 != (int)strlen(WAKELOCK_NAME))
         printf("error writing to file");
}
int main(void)
{
    api_init();
    api_acquire();
   /*after some work*/
    api_release();
}
```

From the above piece of code, i am able to acquire ok but failing in releasing the locks, I am getting return_2 as -1. Can anyone please help me in debugging possible reason of this failure.

Comment: What is the value of `errno`?

Comment: For starters, how about replacing `printf` with `perror`? That way you will be able to see error description.

Comment: What is this `/sys/p/unlock` really? Is it from a custom toy kernel module? In case those are virtual files: the `O_APPEND` flag looks suspicious.

Comment: error is  errno = Operation not permitted

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can not write to /sys/p/lock or /sys/p/unlock, because it is no real file system and these files do not support writing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs?wprov=sfla1

Comment: You definitely can write to sysfs; it depends on if the virtual file supports writing.

Comment: Yes, but I guessed that the file he tries to access, does not support it.

Comment: The write to /sys/p/lock is succeeding but the write to /sys/p/unlock is failing. Trying to understand whats the difference.
Here I have replaced /sys/power with /sys/p.